# why openstack neutron linuxbridge cpu high?

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

I have installed openstack(queens) in my Centos7.4(azure), the architecture is controller + compute.

After installed, I found that `neutron-linuxbridge-agent` had a very high cpu load, mostly 100%. How can I fix that?